# Get part of array string

Tags: php, location, geo, geoip, locate

Hello my output PHP code is :

```
Array ( [country] => BG - Bulgaria )
```

... and he comes from here :

```
<?php
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       print_r(geoCheckIP($ip));
       //Array ( [domain] => dslb-094-219-040-096.pools.arcor-ip.net [country] => DE - Germany [state] => Hessen [town] => Erzhausen )

       //Get an array with geoip-infodata
       function geoCheckIP($ip)
       {
               //check, if the provided ip is valid
               if(!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
               {
                       throw new InvalidArgumentException("IP is not valid");
               }

               //contact ip-server
               $response=@file_get_contents('http://www.netip.de/search?query='.$ip);
               if (empty($response))
               {
                       throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error contacting Geo-IP-Server");
               }

               //Array containing all regex-patterns necessary to extract ip-geoinfo from page
               $patterns=array();

               $patterns["country"] = '#Country: (.*?)&nbsp;#i';

               //Array where results will be stored
               $ipInfo=array();

               //check response from ipserver for above patterns
               foreach ($patterns as $key => $pattern)
               {
                       //store the result in array
                       $ipInfo[$key] = preg_match($pattern,$response,$value) && !empty($value[1]) ? $value[1] : '';
               }

               return $ipInfo;
       }

?>
```

How can I get ONLY the name of the Country like in my case "Bulgaria"? I think it will happen with preg_replace or substr but i dont know what is the better solution now.

Answer (score 2):

substr's probably easiest:

```
$bad_country = 'BG - Bulgaria';
$good_country = substr($bad_country, 5); // start at char 5, 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

if the country is always separated from the acronym by ' - ', do it like this:

```
list($acrn, $country) = explode(' - ', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed that the output will always be in the same format(ie *BG - Bulgaria*, *US - United States*, etc), you could use `explode()`:

```
$array['country'] = "BG - Bulgaria";
$country = explode(" - ", $array['country']);
echo $country[1];
```

This will output "Bulgaria".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    foreach( $list as $v) {
     $temp = explode(' - ', $v);        
     $countries[] = $temp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$patterns["country"] = '#Country:.*-\s+(\w+?)&nbsp;#i';
```

try this one as your pattern

Comment: u already have pattern and i guess you dont want to use preg_replace or substr as it will add extra unnecessary computaion

Answer (score 0):

Change your pattern to this:

```
'#Country: [a-z]{2,} - (.*?)&nbsp;#i'
```

*Assuming the pattern won't change*